# DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given ~ Due to factory (Laravel PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, factory, observers

I am trying to retrieve a date from an object (it returns a string), change it to a DateTime, then add a month and turn it back into a string all inside an observer.

Below is the Observer code:

```
$date = $loans->startDate;
$start = date_create($date);
$startdate = $start->modify('+1 months');
$stringstart = $startdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

LoanPeriods::factory([
                'loans_id' => $loans->id,
                'periodStart' => $loans->startDate,
                'periodEnd' => $stringstart,
        ])->create();
```

When the LoanPeriod factory code is commented out, it runs perfectly. If I do `dd($stringstart);` it returns the value I am expecting. If I do `dd(gettype($date));` it returns a string so I have no clue why when I uncomment the factory code it says

> DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
> given.

It should not be saying that as it is definitely a string. Not an object. I have done a `dd();` on every variable and a `dd(getType());` as well and every time it returns what is expected. Why does adding the factory in (or any other code) somehow cause it to think that `$date` is not a string?

Here is the LoanPeriodFactory.php code:

```
<?php
namespace Database\Factories;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\LoanPeriods;
class LoanPeriodsFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = LoanPeriods::class;
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'interestAmount' => floatval(0),
            'taxAmount' => floatval(0),
            'principleAmount' => floatval(0),
            'paid'=> FALSE,
            'paymentDate'=> null,
        ];
    }
}
```

The LoanPeriod model file:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LoanPeriods extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'loans_id',
        'periodStart',
        'periodEnd',
        'interestAmount',
        'principleAmount',
        'paid',
        'paymentDate'
    ];
}
```

The error:

Whenever the error happens, it points to this line:

```
$start = date_create($date);
```

The Loan Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loans extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'companies_id',
        'amount',
        'startDate',
        'endDate',
        'dateCreated',
        'interestRate',
        'interestPaymentPeriod',
        'interestOnlyPeriod',
        'active',
        'refinanced',
        'loanType'

    ];
}
```

I have tried many different things as well:

1. Tried separating as many things as I could into separate variables to see where the issue was
2. I tried `(new \DateTime($loans->endDate))` but when I do it like this it still returns thestring expected error even when the factory is commented out
3. I also tried `(new DateTime($loan->endDate))` and changed the import to just `use DateTime` instead of `use \DateTime` as seen on list item 2
4. I tried changing the `'periodEnd'` to just accept the `$loans->startDate` directly with no modification and still the same error.